# Approximating current in photoelectric effect

Tags: visible-light, solid-state-physics, photoelectric-effect

I am currently doing an experiment looking at the energy distribution of photoelectrons in the photoelectric effect.

I have done some data collection for different wavelengths of light, and have the following results:

[image]

I understand there is no direct link between photocurrent and backing voltage, however I found this experiment done at Princeton which first uses the equation for the density of states of a free electron gas to approximate the current:

> In this case, we will make only a first order correction to the linear
> approximation. We assume that the conduction band of potassium can be
> approximated as a free electron gas (this is a reasonable
> approximation for most good conductors because the ‘sea of electrons’
> in the conduction band is not significantly perturbed by the nuclei).
> Fig. 4 shows an energy diagram for a one-dimensional conduction band;
> we set the energy to be zero at the bottom of the conduction band. EF
> stands for the Fermi energy of the free electron gas and is equivalent
> to the bandwidth. In 3 dimensions, the density of states of a free
> electron gas is:

$$D(E) = \frac{V}{2\pi^2} (\frac{2m}{\hbar})^{3/2} E^{½}$$

> In order to determine how many electron states can be reached at a
> given photon energy for a given reverse bias, we simply integrate the
> density of states from the lowest possible energy level that can be
> photoexcited to the Fermi energy E_F . The photocurrent should be
> directly proportional to the number of states that can be
> photoexcited. You should be able to work this out to derive an
> equation for the current of the form:

$$ I = A(B^{3/2} - (V-C)^{3/2})$$

> where B should correspond to E_F . Note that in this equation V is the
> reverse bias, ie. it is the negative of the applied voltage.

I have tried just about everything to understand how this equation is derived but seem unable to.

If I integrate from E = 0 to E = E_f, I just don't understand where the voltage comes into it. To me it seems as though there should only be one part:

$$ N = \int_{0}^{E_F} \frac{(2m)^{3/2}Volume}{2\pi\hbar}E^{1/2} \ dE$$
$$ N = \frac{2}{3}\frac{(2m)^{3/2}Volume}{2\pi\hbar} E_F^{3/2}$$

In short, I want to understand how voltage relates to the integral of the Fermi energy, and how this can be made proportional to current.

Answer (score 0):

What I expect to happen with increasing voltage is that the initial phase space of electrons that travel to the anode becomes larger. At threshold (at the stopping potential), it would just be the electrons with a $k$-vector perpendicular to the surface. When the retarding voltage is smaller, electrons within a larger cone of $k$-vectors contribute to the photocurrent. And also a wider range of initial energies and/or energy losses due to inelastic scattering in the metal.

A power law should work over a short range of voltages, but it would be difficult to predict a value for the exponent. So that 3/2 that you found may be empirical.

The voltage range is much smaller than the width of the free-electron band so one should not expect a clear effect of the density of states.